# Passing Date Parameter as NpgsqlParameter in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio

I'm new to `C#`.  I am trying convert the data type of Date from Text.

`cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@dob", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date));`

And I received this throw `exception error`:

`Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Parameter @dob must be set`

Can anyone which experienced in `Postgres db`with `C#` give me some advise here?

Comment: You forgot to set the value. It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: thanks for the guide, I solved it with  cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@dob", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date) { Value = dob });